# How can I filter out Foursquare status updates in 'Facebook for Android'?

Tags: facebook, filter

I have installed Facebook for Android on my android phone.

A friend of mine is disappointed to see all the random stuff going on in the news feed. 
He's particularly not interested in the Foursquare status updates.

Is there an ability to filter the news feed? 
I know that Facebook, when viewed in a webbrowser, has the ability to select 'Hide all by foursquare'.

I'm using version 1.5.1 of 'Facebook for Android' (version released in Januari 2011).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all that they've improved the Facebook app for Android lately, it's still woefully underpowered. I don't see any way to filter anything within the app.

Comment: Guess we'll have to wait a bit then... Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to filter it through the web interface, then you won't see them in the fb app.

Comment: I have found that the web interface works, but I don't use it that often. I prefer the Facebook app.